# WP read user_id from JSON and show it

Tags: json, windows-phone-8.1

I want to show user_id from the following JSON:

[{"username":"Kac26","email":"xklemenx@gmail.com","city":"Slovenj Gradec","id":"15"}]

So I save this JSON to class. I get JSON from my webpage.

My class:

```
public class Class2
{
    public string username{ get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Saving JSON to class:

```
private async void Login_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
string str = user.Text; //get user name from textbox

HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
var response= await http.GetStringAsync("http://mywebpage.com/events/apis/user.php/user=" + str);
}
```

Then I want to show user id in textbox_id when i press button.

```
private  void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
textbox_id.Text = Class2.id;
}
```

But error shows up when I try to reach Class2.id
Anyone know how to do that? And do I save json to class correct?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

In "Saving JSON to class", I don't see where you are actually doing that.  Here's how you would deserialize the string returned by the service:

```
private async void Login_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string str = user.Text; //get user name from textbox

    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetStringAsync("http://mywebpage.com/events/apis/user.php/user=" + str);

    Class2 myClass2 = null;

    try
    {
        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Class2));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response)))
        {
             myClass2 = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream) as Class2;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // serialization error occurred
    }

    // do something with myClass2

}
```

Also, FYI if you don't want the property names on your response class to match the JSON properties (for example, not be lower case), you can use `DataContractAttribute` and `DataMemberAttribute` on your class like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class Class2
{
    [DataMember(name = "username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(name = "email")]
    public string EMail { get; set; }

    [DataMember(name = "city")]
    public string SomeCompletelyDifferentNameForCity { get; set; }

    [DataMember(name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get the following Error when I run this code:
  
`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.Object]'.`
Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Your JSON is an array of objects, so try deserializing to List<Class2>, or change the server to return a single user.

Comment: Hmmmmm, lets say that this is my JSON: http://veligovsek.si/events/apis/user.php?email=mitja.miklav@gmail.com

Can you help me deserialize it in my code? Please :)

Answer (score 0):

`Class2.id` is a static access to a non-static property of `Class2`. You have to create an instance of `Class2` with `new Class2();` at some point and then you can access the property.